# value saveAsTextFile is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, scala

How Can I save a DataFrame as a CSV in HDFS?

I'm trying with this:

```
df.groupBy("Product_ID").agg(collect_list($"Stock")).saveAsTextFile("PATH/results.csv")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not standard part of the API of DataFrames. You can either map it to a RDD, join the row entries to a string and save that or the more flexible way is to use the DataBricks spark-csv package that can be found [here](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv).

If it's just one column you can map it to a RDD and just call `.saveAsTextFile(filename)`

Comment: I only want to save the results in HDFS. I don't know if the best option is to convert it into CSV. There is a easily way to export the results of:
 df.groupBy("Product_ID").agg(collect_list($"Stock")).show
To my directory of HDFS?

Comment: If it's only one column you can just use .rdd on your dataframe and save it using .saveTextFile

Comment: When I save as text file is saving like this:
[40278043620120628,WrappedArray(5824, 9909, 5824, 9909, 9909, 3504)]

There is any way to save like this:
[40278043620120628,5824, 9909, 5824, 9909, 9909, 3504]
???

Comment: I don't know Scala but if you want that you have to map the WrappedArray to a normal list somehow

Answer (score 3):

You're close! You're just missing a `.rdd`! Try this:

```
df.groupBy("Product_ID").agg(collect_list($"Stock")).rdd.saveAsTextFile("PATH/results.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

`df.rdd.saveAsTextFile("xyz")` is the right answer